# Text + variable in qDebug

Tags: qdebug

I want to combine text and variable in qDebug:

```
QString city_name = "London";
qDebug() << QString("You choose CITY:").arg(city_name);
```

It doesn't work and i don't know why. Error is:

```
QString::arg: Argument missing: You choose CITY:, ?????
```

Answer (score 0):

Add %1:

```
QString city_name = "London";
qDebug() << QString("You choose CITY: %1").arg(city_name);
```